# This automated file to dirtree match/sort calculator is getting too complex

Tags: windows, batch-file, count, windows-11

I have this semi-automated file sorting script that, for every subdirectory in `%destination%` check for matches against `%mask%` and count those matches, then write `NumberOfMatches,DirectoryPath` to `matches.csv` for later sorting to find the most matches

```
:count
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:: for each dir in destination count matches for mask
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /ad "%destination%\*" 2^>nul') do (
    set "count="
    for /f %%b in ('dir /b "%%a\%mask%" 2^>nul ^|find /c /v ""') do (
        set "count=    %%b"
        echo !count:~-4!,%%a >>"%tmp%\matches.csv"
    )
)
:: by sorting the results we have a winner
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=, " %%a in ('sort "%tmp%\matches.csv"') do set "fulldir=%%b" & set "count=%%a"
```

This is not entirely ideal since I need to come up with the search masks and keep a list. I think I could find proper matches completely automatically instead by dividing the filename to sets of two or more consecutive words and use them for the search like so (criticism about idea required)

```
set destionation=d:\texts
:: example file
set "orphan=this file name right here.txt" & set "oname=this file name right here"

for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,*" %%i in ("%oname%") do (
    if not "%%i"=="" if not "%%j"=="" set "mask=*%%i %%j*" & call :count
    if not "%%j"=="" if not "%%k"=="" set "mask=*%%j %%k*" & call :count
    if not "%%k"=="" if not "%%l"=="" set "mask=*%%k %%l*" & call :count
    if not "%%l"=="" if not "%%m"=="" set "mask=*%%l %%m*" & call :count
    if not "%%m"=="" if not "%%n"=="" set "mask=*%%m %%n*" & call :count
    if not "%%n"=="" if not "%%o"=="" set "mask=*%%n %%o*" & call :count
    if not "%%o"=="" if not "%%p"=="" set "mask=*%%o %%p*" & call :count
    if not "%%p"=="" if not "%%q"=="" set "mask=*%%p %%q*" & call :count
    if not "%%q"=="" if not "%%r"=="" set "mask=*%%q %%r*" & call :count
)
exit /b
```

This has the undesired result of each different `%mask%` count being recorded on its own and not added up with the others, which would give a better directory match.

For example, my example input `this file name right here.txt` may produce results like this using the first `%mask%` (pair of words) `*this file*`

```
3,d:\texts\word
2,d:\texts\notes
```

And next on the list there would be separate results from the next `%mask%` word pair `*file name*`

```
2,d:\texts\notes
```

I need these results for these different pairs to be added up so the results for these two first pairs would instead look like this

```
3,d:\texts\word
4,d:\texts\notes
```

Comment: If I were you I'd consider using something like python or PowerShell. Batch is fun and all, but there are better tools nowadays.

Comment: @Mat I only know batch but I may understand others. Open to suggestions. What ever can be executed from command line in a simple way would probably be best for this 20-30 batch script team work cluster I got going on here.

Comment: Please post example input and desired output results. These things are easily done in `batch-file`s

Comment: @Gerhard output illustration added to op

Comment: @Compo I tried translating two lines of code from one of my 30 batch scripts to python and it ended up as a whole page of code I didn't understand/couldn't maintain. My statement stands.

Comment: PowerShell is good since it runs OOB from command line